# Получить записи верхнего уровня в MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

Как в MongoDb получить документы **только "верхнего уровня"**, то есть список документов **без поддокументов**?

Например, есть коллекция документов Category с полями:
Id (int), Name (string), Products (Product[])

Нужно получить список всех категорий, **не подтягивая список продуктов** для каждой из них. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Можно исключить объект Products из выборки передав в find в вторым параметром список полей которые нужно выбрать

```
db.collection.find({conditions}, {Products: 0}) // в результате будут все поля кроме Products
```

Подробнее в [документации](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields)